# TortoiseSVN with proxy no auth

Tags: svn, proxy, tortoisesvn

I got problem with TrotoiseSVN. I need to use proxy to connect into the repository. I set up the proxy inside TortoiseSVN and proxy is working fine. But problem is that I should by asked by repo for credentials but I'm not and therefore I'm not able to checkout or commit. To me more exact about setup.

I have to connect in VPN. Then i have to go through proxy inside this VPN to get to the repo. When I try to use Firefox to browse repo (repo is https://) I have to set up proxy connection in Firefox. I'm asked by Firefox for credentials for the proxy. I put them in. Then I'm asked for credentials by svn. I put them in and then i can browse repo using Firefox and https://.

Now with TortoiseSVN I insert credentials for proxy in setting, I try to checkout but I'm not asked for credentials for SVN and get authentication error. There is nothing stored in stored data as TortoiseSVN is clean install and never used for any connection. Does anyone have idea how to force TortoiseSVN to send credentials to SVN?

BTW: I'm limited to use only port 8080 on proxy and 443 for SVN.

Thanks much for any suggestions! :)